# Unable to delete form form inline formset in django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I have a inline formset called WorkExperienceFormset. I am generating form clicking a button. But I am unable to delete the forms. When I click button nothing is happening.

forms.py:

```
WorkExperienceFormset = inlineformset_factory(Employee, WorkExperience, extra=0, min_num=1,
                                                fields = [
                                                    'previous_company_name',
                                                    'job_designation',
                                                    'from_date',
                                                    'to_date',
                                                    'job_description',
                                                ],
                                                widgets = {
                                                        'previous_company_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
                                                        'job_designation': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
                                                        'from_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm has-feedback-left single_cal', 'id': 'single_cal3'}, format='%m/%d/%Y'),
                                                        'to_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm has-feedback-left single_cal', 'id': 'single_cal4'}, format='%m/%d/%Y'),
                                                        'job_description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
                                                },
                                                can_delete = True,
                                                can_order = True,
                                            )
```

template.html:

```
<div class="work-formset">
  {% for work_form in work_formset %}
  <div class="work-form">
    <div class="item form-group">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 label-align">Previous Company Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <!-- <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"> -->
        {{ work_form.previous_company_name }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item form-group">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 label-align">Job Designation</label>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <!-- <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"> -->
        {{ work_form.job_designation }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item form-group">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 label-align">Job Details</label>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <!-- <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"> -->
        {{ work_form.job_description }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item form-group">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 label-align">From Date</label>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <!-- <input id="birthday" class="date-picker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required" type="text"> -->
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          {{ work_form.from_date }}
          <span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left m-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item form-group">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 label-align">To Date</label>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <!-- <input id="birthday" class="date-picker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required" type="text"> -->
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          {{ work_form.to_date }}
          <span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left m-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="work-form-divider" id="">

    </div>
  </div>

  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

script:

```
function cloneForm(selector, prefix) {
      var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
      var total = $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
      var currentFormIndex = total;

      newElement.find(':input').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        var id = 'id_' + name;
        $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
      });

      total++;
      $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);

      var solidLn = '<div class="ln_solid"></div>';
      var deleteBtnId = prefix + '-' + currentFormIndex + '-btn';
      deleteBtn = `<button type="button" value="remove" id="${deleteBtnId}" onClick="deleteForm('${deleteBtnId}', '${prefix}')"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>`
      //deleteBtn = `<a type="button" value="remove" id=${deleteBtnId} onClick='deleteForm("delete", "prefix")'><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>`

      $(selector).after(newElement);
      $(newElement).prepend(deleteBtn);
      $(newElement).prepend(solidLn);

    }

    function deleteForm(btn, prefix) {
      console.log(btn, prefix);
      $(btn).parents('.work-form').remove('.work-form');
      console.log("Button: " + $(btn).parents('.work-form'));
    }
```

`cloneForm()` is working. But `deleteForm()` is not working. From the `console.log` I can see that `deleteForm()` is called when I press delete the button. Somehow `.remove()` is not working.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems for this line `$(btn).parents('.work-form').remove('.work-form');`

`.parents()` -> The parents() method returns all ancestor elements of the selected element.

`.remove()` -> Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

Since `remove()` is the filter for the object in question, in this case, the object in question is just the single element with the id `.work-form`, therefore not containing any `.work-form` elements. Make sure to check your `DOM` and find that you have `work-form` elements present as a child.

You can simply solve this by using an unique identifier for the form in question instead of using the `work-form`
element.

Comment: `var formId = 'id_' + prefix + '-' + currentFormIndex;
      deleteBtn = `<button type="button" value="remove" id="${deleteBtnId}" onClick="deleteForm('${formId}', '${prefix}')"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>`
function deleteForm(form, prefix) {
      console.log(form, prefix);
      $(form).remove();

    }`

i have done this.. but not working

Comment: I would recommend you to trace down your DOM tree and indeed verify that the elements that you intend are actually appearing with parent/child relationship. You can also use the `.find()` method to locate an element. And please update the relevant error traces to the question

Comment: Can you profide an example of the solution to this problem??? It will be helpful. I new to this.